# Catkin seperate compilers for different packages

Tags: cmake, catkin

I have two packages in a catkin workspace, one of which must be built with clang and the other must be built with gcc. From what I've read online, changing the compiler inside CmakeLists.txt with set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "gcc") is frowned upon (and can even result in [endless loops](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=14841)), but I also can't find a way to have package-specific compilers using catkin.

Is there a generally accepted way to do this?